# Making menu (div) scale down when screen is resized

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a menu on a website: http://bit.ly/18zG5i7. I am trying to make this menu scale down if the window is resized smaller.

CSS

```
#menu_wrap
{
    max-width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:50%;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom:0%;
    left:2%;
    z-index: 500;
}

#menu 
{
    background: #FFD700; 
    border-color:#000000;
    width: 180px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu_wrap">
    <div id="menu">
        <ul id="navbar">
            <li><a href="#"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: change the `width` of `#menu` to percentage instead of pixels

Answer (score 1):

For better display in all type of screens (ie. pc, mobile, ipad, etc) you want to use `@media screen` please refer the [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Because web-site will not fit to all screens, you want to set diff. properties for diff. screens.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `max-height:100%;` and a `min-height:auto;` Also do that with the width.